# Snowflake Query to fetch 3 latest versions of back up tables for a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake query to fetch 3 latest versions of back up tables for a table
example:
`if table EMP is having backups like EMP_BKP1,EMP_BKP2,EMP_BKP3,EMP_BKP4,EMP_BKP5 Then i need to fetch latest 3 backup tables from these`

Appriciate your help.

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question and this isn’t a free code writing service. Please update your question with the code you’ve managed to write and ask a question about a specific issue you are facing

Comment: edited my query, i have tried
`SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema'
  AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'EMP%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC;`

but looks like this query is giving all the tables

Comment: Hi the View  Information_schema.Tables will displays objects for which the current role for the session has been granted access privileges, do you have access granted to the tables which you think are missing from the  query that you are using.

Comment: If you only want the first 3 records from your query then just add TOP 3 to it

Comment: how about `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema'   AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'EMP%' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC limit 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give the results to keep latest 3 backup tables.

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME AS original_string,CREATED,
  case when table_name like '%BKP%' THEN SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,1,POSITION('_' IN TABLE_NAME) - 1) 
  ELSE TABLE_NAME END AS extracted_string
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TRAINING_SCHEMA'
  AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_BKP%'
  AND ORIGINAL_STRING<>EXTRACTED_STRING
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACTED_STRING ORDER BY CREATED DESC) >3
;
```